# is there possibility to access the no of times we open the each application in device programmatically in android?

Tags: android

As I am working on access the all applications in device in to one application and by clicking on each application it is showing the date and time of install and package name version code.I want to know if there is possibility to access the how many times we open the each application from install  date to till now by programmatically.please provide any code available.

thanks in advance, teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a variable in your application increment that variable and store that in a database.. In iphone i use NSUserDefaults

Comment: But my doubt is If we download the app from market and install in phone. Now i create a app that will display all app in the phone. when we click on each I have to know count how many times it open download app.Is it possibility and how.